# RelativeLayout set view to the right of a centered view

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, android-relativelayout

I try to set a view to the right of a first view and bottom align them inside a RelativeLayout.

The following code looks to me like it should work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="#999999"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/v2"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/v1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/v1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But the result is not really what i've expected.

[image: Result]

What is the problem here?

Just to be clear what i expect: both cubes should be bottom aligned against each other and the red cube should be to the right of the white one (outside).

**Edit:**

I have found the problem. it's not this layout, but the parent list, where it is included (it's a propriety HorizontalListView). it seems to resize its child views somehow and that causes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                android:background="#999999"
                android:padding="10dp" >

    <View
            android:id="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" />

    <View
            android:id="@+id/v2"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="#FF0000" 
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/v1" 
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/v1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/v1"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Am I right? ;)

Comment: Weird, the exact same layout does not work for me. same issue. it must be some sort of scaling problem, but that should actually be handled correctly by android. i have tested it on a Galaxy Nexus and on a Nexus 10, same result.

Comment: the problem was actually the parent view, so the question is not really valid. i just flagged a random answer as accepted...

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me.  My guess is that the sp for whatever you are testing on is scaling down from the default sp=dp.  This would make your dp padding push the block over, which it already  might since the amount of available space between the grey and white blocks is:

```
(300-200)/2 - 10 = 40
```

and your red block is 50.

If you want more consistent results use dp since sp will scale based on preferences and is usually used for text scaling.

Comment: Did you remove the padding too?

Comment: the problem was actually the parent view, so the question is not really valid. i just flagged a random answer as accepted... sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use sp as the unit. Try instead to use dp (device pixels). This would take the device into consideration. In your case, the images are not scaled properly and hence this result. You could also set the gravity on the view v2. Something like :

```
android:gravity="botton|right"
```

Or you could also try setting the baseline to something like :

```
android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/v1"
```

and set the alignRight to something like :

```
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/v1"
```

Comment: sorry, i used sp on mistake. i corrected the question. it does not make a difference though. Using gravity in a RealtiveLayout seems awkward to me, since the items should be positioned with the Relativelayout parameters.

Comment: Did setting the layout_alignBaseLine and layout_alignRight work ?

Comment: the problem was actually the parent view, so the question is not really valid. i just flagged a random answer as accepted... sorry for the confusion.